# Is that a correct way to use Dispose Method?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, idisposable

Here i used the dispose method in aspx.cs, but i am not sure wheather the way of disposing the objects is done it in correct way.
Obvisoly i surf it from net and used it in my code,can u please say wheather the objects is disposing in correct format.

This is my method in aspx.cs

```
public List<CausesField> list(DataTable dt)
        {
             List<CausesField> lst = new List<CausesField>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                    using (CausesField SignUpDetails = new CausesField())
                    {
                        SignUpDetails.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                        SignUpDetails.LastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
                        SignUpDetails.Birthdate = row["BirthDay"].ToString();
                        SignUpDetails.Gender = row["Gender"].ToString();

                        lst.Add(SignUpDetails);
                        SignUpDetails.Dispose();
                    }


            }
            return lst;

        }
```

My Class file:

```
public  class CausesField:IDisposable
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }  public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Birthdate { get; set; }  public string Gender { get; set; }

         private Component component = new Component();

        private bool disposed = false;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
                // and unmanaged resources.
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources.
                    component.Dispose();
                }

            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `using` statement automatically calls `Dispose` at the end of the block, so you should not call it yourself again.

Also, in general, unless you are holding onto some external resources (locks, file handles, sockets, database connections, etc.) or unmanaged memory (and I suspect this to be the case in your case), you should not have a finalizer or a `Dispose` method. The garbage collector takes care of freeing up managed memory.

Comment: disposing method is called at the end of the block.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to dispose the instance while using "using" statement. The object provided to the `using` statement implements the IDisposable interface so that call the `dispose()` method in finally block.

Your above  `using (CausesField SignUpDetails = new CausesField())` statement will be equivalent to following code:

```
CausesField SignUpDetails = new CausesField();
try
{
//To do code here
}
finally
{
    if(SignUpDetails!=null)
    {
       SignUpDetails.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - a  correction; using doesn't implement IDSiposable, using works for only those objects which implements IDisposable :)